# AWS share custom AMI build instructions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

I want to use a trusted cloud provider (I chose Amazon, maybe there is an alternative) to share an application without leaking its code.

The application is supposed to use the customer data, and I want to prove to him that I am not using his data for any other purpose.

So, is there any way to ask Amazon for publishing the instructions I followed to create an Amazon Machine Image which contains the application so that the user can happily instantiate the machine send it his data without any fear of any misuse?

Please help me, thanks a lot

Comment: What do you mean by "anyway to publish the instructions"? Can't you just give them a PDF with the instructions? Do you want them to run an EC2 instance, or use your _existing_ instance? Feel free to edit your question to clarify what you are wanting to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an AMI and grant permission for your user to launch an Amazon EC2 instance in their own AWS Account that uses that AMI.

Any data they place on the instance will remain within *their* AWS Account and you will not have access to it.

However, they might argue that there could be some software installed in the AMI that **secretly sends their data to another computer** on the Internet, so they might prefer to install the software themselves rather than use a pre-built AMI. However, unless they look through your entire source code, they wouldn't know whether your software itself is stealing data, either!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, that is exactly what I want, and since they can claim that my software can steal their data I wished if it is possible that I can ask amazon for publishing the steps I made to build this AMI. And since it seems there is not a way to do that, is it possible for the user to configure a firewall around this machine so he can be sure his data is not send to any other place ?

Comment: I looked for how to make a firewall and I figured out that is easy. So with a firewall around my opaque machine both of me and the customer are safe.